# Deserialize FontAwesome Yaml Using YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, yamldotnet

I have a Yaml file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/src/icons.yml

And a class:

```
public class IconSearch
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Can you tell me how I can deserialize the yaml to an IEnumerable of objects?

I expect something like this to work, but it returns null - I'm guessing it's because one of my properties is not the root node (icons). Instead, I'm trying to serialize the children of the root?

```
var input = new StringReader(reply);
var yaml = new YamlStream();
yaml.Load(input);
var icons = deserializer.Deserialize<IconSearch>(input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are trying to deserialize to seems to be missing properties. 
I went the round about way of converting yaml to json to csharp and this is class that was generated:

```
public class Rootobject
{
public Icon[] icons { get; set; }
}

public class Icon
{
public string[] categories { get; set; }
public object created { get; set; }
public string[] filter { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public string unicode { get; set; }
public string[] aliases { get; set; }
public string[] label { get; set; }
public string[] code { get; set; }
public string url { get; set; }
}
```

Resources used :
[YAML to JSON online](http://yamltojson.com/)
[JSON to CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/) (I used Paste special in visual studio)

Use this to deserialize

```
var icons = deserializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(input);
```

**Update**
I have commented out the line that you use to create YamlStream as it is not required (it positions the reader to the end of the stream instead of the beginning, which would explain why you were getting null earlier). Your main method looks as follows and works. I have also fixed the bug that Antoine mentioned

```
public static void Main()
{
    string filePath = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/src/icons.yml";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string reply = client.DownloadString(filePath);
    var input = new StringReader(reply);
    //var yamlStream = new YamlStream();
    //yamlStream.Load(input);
    Deserializer deserializer = new Deserializer();
    //var icons = deserializer.Deserialize<IconSearch>(input);

    //Testing my own implementation
    //if (icons == null)
    //    Console.WriteLine("Icons is null");

    //Testing Shekhar's suggestion
    var root = deserializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(input);
    if (root == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Root is null");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to have worked either. I've made a .NET fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qVGZ1D It makes sense that my implementation does work because the property names aren't right, but I did assume I didn't need all of the properties from the yaml to be there. Is there a way to deserialize to different property names like you can do with JSON.NET? Can anyone show a working fiddle?

Comment: There is a bug in your fiddle. You are testing the wrong variable in `if (icons == null) Console.WriteLine("Root is null");`. I made it work here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JXiRjX

Comment: Regarding the casing, you may want to can use `CamelCaseNamingConvention`, or decorate each member with `YamlMemberAttribute`.

Comment: @AntoineAubry I know thats not ideal naming convention, but curiously it was generated by Visual Studio. I guess they don't want to dictate what naming convention you should use.

Comment: Thanks guys - I see where I went wrong now. Since I prefer the data to sit in a list of more generic objects (like IconSearch) so other implementation of typography searching can be used, I'm using automapper to map the two lists together.